# How can I sync a network folder in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, sync, dropbox

I have a network folder at work that I would like to be accessible from home. I have purchased some space in Yandex.Disk (basically just another Dropbox clone, so let's just imagine I'm using Dropbox) and tried to create a symbolic link to the folder. Unfortunately, I discovered that symbolic links can't lead to network folders.

So my question is basically how I can sync a network folder via Dropbox.

Comment: Are you sure you created a *symbol link*? Because it can point anywhere. It’s *junctions* that are restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not create a reparsepoint for a network folder.

Copy the contents of the network drive to a folder in Dropbox using a sync software that will mirror the contents of the network drive.

Comment: Well, this is what I came to in the end. I'm now using Qtdsync (free and open source) for 1-way synchronization every hour. Unfortunately I couldn't find a user-friendly free solution for 2-way sync, but 1-way is fine too.

Comment: Bvckup beta is free and good. Rsync is free. Syncback is also free.